# Get the same window.screen.height and window.screen.width on different browsers when screen CSS pixel ratio is higher than 1

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, smartphone

I need to detect window.screen.height and window.screen.width with javascript. But testing on a device with a css pixel ratio greater than 1 I get different results in multiple browsers.

Testing on Samsung Galaxy S3, Resolution: 1280x720 and CSS pixel ratio: 2 I get the following result:

Stock browser: 1280x720
Firefox: 1280x720
Opera: 640x360
Chrome: 640x360

Is it somehow posible to get same result across different browsers?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```

For all type of devices including iOS. 
Use it within your document ready function.
and use media query for pixel ratio in css here is the link for all mobile media query [standard device media query](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: That gives me the browsers width. I need something like:
<br>
`$(screen).width();`
`$(screen).height();`

Comment: no, it will give you window width and height not browsers check it in your mobile device. are you making mobile site or application or what?

Comment: Using: $(window).width(); and $(window).height();  Testing on Samsung Galaxy S3, Resolution: 1280x720 and CSS pixel ratio: 2 I get the following result:

Stock browser: 567x360 Firefox: 308x360 Opera: 567x360 Chrome: 640x360 Opera Mini 488x343

I am making a mobile site.

Kind Regards

Comment: always use chrome and safari for mobile device(galaxy s3 also) and 1280x 720 is your screen resolution it effects only images and it gives you exact screen width and height you just implement that one also you need to minus your browser's top bar from given height

Comment: I do not quite understand?

Comment: $(window).innerWidth(); once try this.